# Difference between LOAM Continuous and LOAM Velodyne

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see multiple packages that recovered LOAM Continuous and Velodyne from the pre-Kaarta repositories. I would consider a velodyne sensor a continuously rotating sensor, so it's a little unclear to me the difference or specialization of the separate Velodyne package. I couldn't find any differences describing the differences.

The back-and-forth version is used for a rotating 2D hokuyo-like sensor configuration. There are references to the continuous version in the LOAM paper but nothing describing the Velodyne variant's differentiation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316933/difference-between-loam-continuous-and-loam-velodyne/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, I figured it out.

Back and forth refers to the hokuyo-like system spinning the lidar sweeping back and forth, continuous is the lidar spinning continuously without sweeping in the opposite direction, and velodyne is for continuously rotating 3D lidars.

Posting answer here for posterity if anyone else also did not make that distinction

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4